Get Request with Body using RestTemplate in Spring Boot 3
I want to send a GET request with a request body in Spring Boot 3 via RestTemplate
Note - Using exchange(URI, HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity(with_the_body_set), ...) by itself does not work
Most resources online (e.g. this) are for Spring Boot 2, which used httpclient v4 I believe
However, I am using Spring Boot 3, which uses httpclient v5
How can I achieve this with - RestTemplate (preferred) or via HttpClient (last resort)?
Note - I know this is horrid, but I am the client here with no control over the server

Http requests can't have request body with GET method.
The basic idea behind this is that client is asking for a particular type of data from the server like kind of findByX() calls.
It can be argued that what if data to be sent depends on some type of condition?
It is absolutely possible. In these cases, client is expected to either send the conditional data to include in URI or in request query parameters.
MDN docs reference for the same:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET

Having said that, i understand your concern. Sometimes it is horrific for developers using the external dependencies not being maintained anymore or not following proper design principals.
Here is some working config with rest client i could come up with and it is working fine for GET requests with request body. Please feel free to modify it as per your needs.
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


public class RestClientConfig {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public RestClientConfig() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    }

    public String getWithBody(Object requestBody) {

        return restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:7070/test-url", HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(requestBody), String.class).getBody();

    }

}

and apache client dependency:
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
</dependency>

Controller code used for testing:
@GetMapping("/test-get-request-with-request-body")
public ResponseEntity<Object> testGetWithRequestBody(@RequestBody Object body) {
    RestClientConfig restClientConfig = new RestClientConfig();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(restClientConfig.getWithBody(body), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("/test-url")
public ResponseEntity<Object> testGetWithRequestBody2(@RequestBody Object body) {
    String response = "[" + body.toString().concat(",").concat(body.toString()) + "]";
    System.out.println(response);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}

Hope it helps!!

thanks! I agree, but a lot of the time, you do not have control over external factors. it has been done in an older version, (refer to the link in my question).

I can understand your concern. I've updated my answer with a working and tested example. Please have a look at it. Thanks.
